# Drawable states with colors (not drawables)

Tags: java, android, colors

I want to give a view a background color with the following behavior: The background should be green while the view is pressed and black otherwise.

This selector works

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:drawable="@drawable/green" android:state_pressed="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/black"/>

</selector>
```

But for doing that I need to create a nine patch 3x3 file with the desired color. How can I reach the same behavior but giving the color code rather a drawable?

Thanks

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Just use the color. From the [docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html):

> A color resource can also be used as a drawable in XML. For example, when creating a state list drawable, you can reference a color resource for the android:drawable attribute (android:drawable="@color/green").

Comment: Using android:drawable="@color/green" the i got the following error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'drawable' with value '@color/green').

Comment: You still need to define the color. Follow the link I provided and click on "color resource" to see how that is done.

Comment: It crashes when I declare a color and use it as background =(

Answer (score 4):

You can do this with a [color state list](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/color-list-resource.html), they are the same thing as the drawable state list in your code posted. You can also create a [shape drawable](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#Shape) and still use the drawable code used above.